# PYTHON: Extract Non-English words and iterate it over a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, text, nlp, nltk

I have a table of about 30,000 rows and need to extract non-English words from a column named `dummy_df`  from a `dummy_df` dataframe. I need to put the non-english words in an adjacent column named `non_english`.

A dummy data is as thus:

```
dummy_df = pandas.DataFrame({'outcome':    ["I want to go to church",  "I love Matauranga", "Take me to  Oranga Tamariki"]})
```

My idea is to extract non-English words from a sentence, and then iterate the process over a dataframe. I was able to accurately extract non-English words from a sentence with this code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('words')
from nltk.corpus import words

words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())

sent = "I love Matauranga"
" ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent) \
         if not w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
```

The result of the above code is `'Matauranga'` which is perfectly correct.

But when I try to iterate the code over a dataframe using this code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('words')
from nltk.corpus import words

def no_english(text):
  words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
  " ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(text['outcome']) \
         if not w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())

dummy_df['non_english'] = dummy_df.apply(no_english, axis = 1)
print(dummy_df)
```

I got an undesirable result in that the `non_english` column has `none` value instead of the desired non-english words (see below):

```
                       outcome non_english
0       I want to go to church        None
1            I love Matauranga        None
2  Take me to  Oranga Tamariki        None
3                                     None
```

Instead, the desired result should be:

```
                       outcome        non_english
0       I want to go to church        
1            I love Matauranga        Matauranga
2  Take me to  Oranga Tamariki        Oranga Tamariki
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `return` in your function:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('words')
from nltk.corpus import words

def no_english(text):
    words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
    return " ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(text['outcome']) \
           if not w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())

dummy_df['non_english'] = dummy_df.apply(no_english, axis = 1)
print(dummy_df)
```

output:

```
                       outcome      non_english
0       I want to go to church                 
1            I love Matauranga       Matauranga
2  Take me to  Oranga Tamariki  Oranga Tamariki
```